# Reference request for the existence of triangulation of surfaces

Tags: reference-request, surfaces

I would like to read a self-contained proof of the theorem of Rado that states that any second countable topological surface admits a triangulation. Actually, I would be content with the compact case.

References that are freely available online would be great. Book references are welcome too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is proved in a paper by Carsten Thomassen, [*The Jordan-Schonflies Theorem and the Classification of Surfaces*](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Thomassen116-131.pdf), using graph-theoretic techniques.