# the Euler characteristic of $K\#K$

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm trying to find the Euler characteristic of $K\#K$, here $K$ is the Klein bottle. I tried to use the fact that $\chi(A\cup B)=\chi(A)+\chi(B)-\chi(A\cap B)$ but it seems not working hence I'm thinking about using other method to solve it. I'm looking for some ideas here.

Comment: @Anik, Xin: `\#` produces $\#$.

Comment: thank you @AsafKaragila

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Euler characteristic of a connected sum of surfaces $S_1$ and $S_2$ is given by $$\chi(S_1 \# S_2) = \chi(S_1) + \chi(S_2) - 2.$$
Recall that $\chi(K)=0$ fo the Klein bottle.

Reference: [Euler characteristic of a connected sum of surfaces.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1981831/euler-characteristic-of-a-connected-sum-of-surfaces)

Comment: Hence $\chi(K$#$K)=2\chi(K)-2=0-2=-2$ ? However, it doesn't work for torus, where we can obtain that $\chi(T)=1$ but $\chi(T$#$T)=-2\neq \chi(T)+\chi(T)-2$

Comment: @XinHu But $\chi(T)=0$, so it does work.

Comment: Is there a way to prove that formula without referring to triangulations?